# can't figure out why my entry() widget is returning null

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've been trying to pass data from an entry box inside a function to another function but the entry.get() function seems to be returning nothing. here is a part of my code. thanks guys

```
def cubedim():

    dimensionframeclear()
    length = 0.0
    length1label = Label(DimensionFrame, text="Length", font=7)
    length1label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    cubelength = Entry(DimensionFrame, textvariable=length)
    cubelength.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5)

    calculatebutton = Button(DimensionFrame, text= "Calculate")
    calculatebutton.grid(row=1,column=4)
    return length

def totalamount():
    

    if var1.get() == 1:
        length = cubedim()
        dimensionofgift = length * length
    
    if var5.get() == 1:
        paperprice = 0.4
    elif var5.get() == 2:
        paperprice = 0.75

    itembow = int(var3.get())
    itemcard = int(var4.get())
    characterlength = len(CardMsg.get())
    if itembow == 1:
        pricebow = 1.5
    else:
        pricebow = 0
    if itemcard == 1:
        pricecard = 0.5
    else:
        pricecard = 0
    subtotal = dimensionofgift * paperprice + pricecard + pricebow + (characterlength*0.5)
    return subtotal
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. However, this question comes up at least once a week and the problem is almost always because you're calling a function before the user has had a chance to enter any data.

Comment: You didn't call any `.get()` on `Entry` widget in your posted code.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't call .get() on Entry anywhere, so it is not clear what you are asking about. That said, @BryanOakley is probably right and you are probably calling the function before there is any data.